# why i can't get full base64 string inside array ionic 3?

Tags: typescript, base64, ionic3

[image]I want to convert multiple Images simultaneously inside for loop in ionic 3

my code is:

```
   for (let i in serviceData) {
    // for(let i=0; i< this.adviceArray.length; i++) {
      console.log("online advices", serviceData[i]);
      this.texto = serviceData[i].texto;
      console.log("check online this.texto ", this.texto );
      this.imagen = serviceData[i].imagen;
      console.log("check online this.imagen", this.imagen);

      this.convertToDataURLviaCanvas(serviceData[i].imagen, "image/jpeg").then(base64 => {
        console.log("online base64", base64);
        this.base64Image = base64;
        console.log("online this.base64Image", this.base64Image);
        // this.adviceArrays64.push({'texto': this.texto, 'imagen': this.base64Image});
      });
      console.log("outer online this.base64Image", this.base64Image);
      this.adviceArrays64.push({'texto': this.texto, 'imagen': this.base64Image});
      console.log("online this.adviceArrays64", this.adviceArrays64);
      this.storage.set("travelTips64", this.adviceArrays64);
    }
```

but not getting full base64 strings of all images.

How can i convert image url in base64 strings inside array and display all converted images in offline mode ionic 3?

please give me solution as soon as possible.

Comment: sorry your code is not giving any clue as to why this doesn't work;/ can you share your full code? specifically what you do in this method: this.convertToDataURLviaCanvas

Comment: thanks, this issue is solved

Answer (score 1):

solved above issue using below function,

```
convertToDataURLviaCanvas(url, outputFormat) {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => 
{
    let img = new Image();
    img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
    img.onload = function () {
        let canvas = <HTMLCanvasElement>document.createElement('CANVAS'),
            ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
            dataURL;
        canvas.height = 1000;
        canvas.width = 1000;
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

        dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
        //callback(dataURL);
        canvas = null;
        resolve(dataURL);
    };
    img.src = url;
});
```

}

when you want converted images from array, call that function in your array as below:

```
let base64Image;
for (let i in serviceData) {
 this.imagen = serviceData[i].imagen;
 this.convertToDataURLviaCanvas(this.imagen, "image/jpeg").then(base64 => {
  base64Image = base64;
  this.texto = serviceData[i].texto;
  this.adviceArrays64.push({'texto': this.texto, 'imagen': base64Image});
   this.storage.set("travelTips64Image", this.adviceArrays64);
  });
}
```